# In React or Javascript how do we provide a custom Document Id for Google Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am using React with cloud Firestore
I am trying to add my own document id instead of one being automatic generated. If we can not do this, is there a way to get a callback to get the document id created when the data is submitted?

```
firebase.firestore()
.collection("user5d")
.document("custom-id")
.add({
    urn: randomNumber,
    line1: "some text",
    line2: "line 2 text",
    slashColor: "green",
    textColor: "white",
  });
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. Isn't the `.document("custom-id")` working for you?

Comment: I am trying to create record but .document("somethingcustom") do not work. I get the follow error
_firestore__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_15__.default.firestore(...).collection(...).document is not a function

Comment: Ah yeah, the function is called `doc()` so: `.doc("custom-id")` should work. See the code samples on : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Comment: Okay Just spotted that. Thanks. I also notice that it .doc("custom") only works with set().  Can we use add()  to prevent overwriting data or do Firestore require unique id's

Comment: `add()` is called on a collection to add a new document with a generated ID. If you want to only update a document if it already exists, use `update` instead of `set`. That call will only succeed if the document already exists. Also see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data (same page as before, but further down).

Answer (score 6):

To clarify the differences between the methods:

**.add()** -> Adds a document in the collection with an auto-generated document ID. You can use this on a [`CollectionReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference) only. For example:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("colName").add({...})
```

**.set()** -> Creates a new document in a collection however unlike `.add()`, you need to specify the document ID. This method can be called on a [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) only. For example:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("colName").doc("docID").set({...})
```

**.update()** -> Updates an existing document in the collection. You need to specify the document ID. Similar to `.set()`, this method can be called on a [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) only. For example:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("colName").doc("docID").update({...})
```

You can use `.set()` to update a document as well but it will overwrite rest of the fields unless you specify the merge property in [SetOptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.SetOptions) like `.set({...}, {merge: true})`